# The Java client of kubernetes retrieves the 'status. phase' of the pod for Terminating status, which is' Running '

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-java-client

I am a newcomer to Kubernetes and I would like to know if there are better attributes to accurately describe the state of pod

```
Kubernetes version: Kubernetes v1.27.3
java client maven:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
    <version>18.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am conducting testing in a Kubernetes cluster with two nodes. I am shutting down the Kubelet service on the slave node to simulate a loss of connectivity from the slave node, allowing the pod of the slave node to be automatically scheduled to the master node

When I use the following command:

```bash
kubectl get po -n my-namespace -o wide
```

we can see

```
nginx1-74499f547c-gbdzf                     1/1     Running       0              6h10m   10.244.0.55   kylin-master     <none>           <none>
nginx1-74499f547c-xndkm                     1/1     Terminating   0              8h      10.244.2.24   kylin-worker02   <none>           <none>
```

Obviously, the status of `nginx1-74499f547c-xndkm` is `Terminating`

But when I use the following code to retrieve the pod and traverse it to find a pod with the same name

```java
CoreV1Api coreV1Api = new CoreV1Api();
V1PodList v1PodList;
try{
    v1PodList = coreV1Api.listNamespacedPod(tenxOpenApiConfig.getTeamSpace(), null, null, null, info, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    for (V1Pod item : v1PodList.getItems()) {
       // .....
    }
} 
// ......
```

[image]

The name of pod is `nginx1-74499f547c-xndkm`, but `item.status.phase="Running"` .

I can't understand why this is happening, is it a bug? Still, `status.phase` is not suitable for representing pod status.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: You have a bug in your question, I think you meant to write `item.status.phase="Running"`

Comment: From what you show, yes, the values should match. You can learn more about Pod and Container states [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase)

Comment: For debugging, you can add e.g. `--v=6` to **any** `kubectl` command to determine the underlying REST API calls against the API server i.e. `kubectl get pod/nginx1-74499f547c-xndkm --namespace={namespace} --v=6` will include something of the form `https://{api-server}/api/v1/namespaces/my-namespace/pods/https://192.168.1.150:16443/api/v1/namespaces/tailscale/pods/ts-ackal-healthcheck-server-m2vq9-0`. You can then either `kubectl get ---raw {that url}` or you can run `kubectl proxy` and then browse the same. You ought be able to do the same with the Java SDK (unfamiliar with it).

Comment: Another way to understand the Kubernetes API is to browse the comprehensive docs. For example for v1.29 here's the definition of [`PodStatus`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.29/#podstatus-v1-core) which details `phase` and here's [`ContainerState`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.29/#containerstate-v1-core)

Comment: @DazWilkin Thank you for your help. I have fixed the bug in the question; For the `nginx1-74499f547c-xndkm` in the question,  [status.containerStatuses](https://img2.imgtp.com/2024/03/08/B1Z4dr3P.png) doesn't seem to have any useful information about determining whether the status is Terminating. However, I have learned a lot of new knowledge from your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;dr**
Kubernetes Pods and containers doesn't have `Terminating` as status, and kubectl prints the status based on multiple fields in the Pod object to be more concise (not just `pod.status.phase`, like `pod.metadata.deletionTimestamp`). Let me explain below in more details.

**More details**
When a pod is being deleted for any reason (e.g. Node failure or manual deletion), it doesn't happen immediately as it could be disruptive to the application running inside, so kubernetes gives a `TERM`(aka. `SIGTERM`) signal to the containers inside the pod first to give it some time to terminate gracefully. After some time (defined in `pod.spec.terminationGracePeriodSeconds`, defaults to `30`) if the containers aren't terminated yet, it kills them.
During this period, containers are actually running, so that's why kubernetes reports the containers and the pods as running.
However, when the pod is being deleted, kubernetes sets `pod.metadata.deletionTimestamp` to the time the delete was issued.
Kubectl is smart enough to detect this and show the status of Pod as `Terminating` when it sees this.

**Documentation**
There is a nice documentation about this [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination).

Let me highlight a useful paragraph:

> Note: When a Pod is being deleted, it is shown as Terminating by some kubectl commands. This Terminating status is not one of the Pod phases. A Pod is granted a term to terminate gracefully, which defaults to 30 seconds. You can use the flag --force to terminate a Pod by force.

**Additional advice**
You can see the pod mostly* as you see it in the code by using `-o yaml`. Example:

```
kubectl get pod -n my-namespace -o yaml
```

- The reason I am saying mostly* is because kubectl omit `.metadata.managedFields` when viewing any object (including pods) as they are likely won't be useful for you. If you want to make kubectl shows it, you can add `--show-managed-fields` to the kubectl command. I mentioned this just for completion of the answer, but if you are starting kubernetes I would recommend ignoring them. There is documentation about them [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/server-side-apply/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have carefully read your answer and it feels very detailed. Not only have I found a solution, but I have also learned more about kubernetes from it.